# How to mask an integer field in database and also make sure it does not fail required validation in the application code

Tags: vb.net, validation, masking

1) I want to Mask an integer field (VSN Number) in the database.

2) There is a validation in the code which determines the VSN is valid or invalid.

3) The masked VSN Number should pass the validation.

### Below is the validation code.

```
Protected Overrides Function IsValid(ByVal vsn As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim vsn As String = vsn.Trim

        '-- Rules 1: Lengh is 9 include the check digit
        If Not vsn.Length = 9 Then
            Return False
        End If

        '-- Rules 2: All digit must be numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(vsn) Then
            Return False
        End If

        '-- Rules 3: Weight factor and divide by 11 remainder must be 0
        Dim sumOfWeightValue As Integer = CInt(Mid(vsn, 1, 1))*1
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 2, 1))*4
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 3, 1))*3
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 4, 1))*7
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 5, 1))*5
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 6, 1))*8
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 7, 1))*6
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 8, 1))*9
        sumOfWeightValue += CInt(Mid(vsn, 9, 1))*10

        sumOfWeightValue = sumOfWeightValue Mod 11

        If sumOfWeightValue <> 0 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function
```

---

Comment: and your question is .... ?  BTW please do not use the same name for a local variable as an existing parameter.  It leads to confusion!  Also this looks to be a vb question not sql

Comment: ok Jon. well i need to come up with a sql script to mask the existing VSN Number field so that masked VSN Number that will be generated through the script should also satisfy the  VSN Number Validation mentioned above.

INPUT :  VSN Number
OUTPUT : Masked VSN Number

I can provide you sample VSN Number if you need.

Comment: Are you saving you want to validate twice?  Once in VB code above and then again in SQL?

Comment: Is this for secrecy purposes in the database?  If so, much more correct would be to mask the value before sending it to database, otherwise anyone who has hacked your db can read your masking routine and de-crypt easily

Comment: I dont want to validate in SQL as such. I only want that the masked number that the sql script generates from the supplied VSN, should not be an invalid VSN number whenever the validation occurs on it, inside the VB application.

Yes it is for secrecy purposes.

Comment: The sql script that will be used for masking will be a one time activity and would not be stored in the db.

Comment: So why do you want SQL to mask it - why not mask in VB - much more efficient not doing a db call with all the overhead

Comment: We do not want to make any code changes in the VB application.  And the script to mask the VSN Numbers will be executed manually in the database. i hope i have answered the question !

Comment: OK so what logic do you want to use for your mask?

Comment: It can be any logic, the output of which will still be a valid VSN.

Comment: And what logic have you tried?

Comment: Tried putting a logic like this {first 3#}{middle 3#}{last3#} to {middle}{last}{first}. Which did not work out.